Move the arcore_flutter_plugin node according to the camera direction
I am implementing an AR screen using arcore_flutter_plugin, and I used a formula to calculate my current location and the location of the corresponding point to display the node, but when I used the geolocator library, the heading value was set to 0.0 by default, so I got the camera direction through the compassX library.
Even if I calculate the heading using radians for the value calculated from the latitude and longitude, the node does not appear in the exact location, and there is a difference.
void _addSphere(ArCoreController controller) {
  double? poss = _lastRead?.heading;

  List<double> targetLongitudepol =  [];
  List<double> targetLatitudepol = [];

  double? currentLongitude = position?.longitude;
  double? currentLatitude = position?.latitude;

  for(int i=0; i < targetLongitudepol.length; i++) {


    double? deltaLongitude = targetLongitudepol[i] - currentLongitude!;
    double? deltaLatitude = targetLatitudepol[i] - currentLatitude!;
    double xDistance = longitudeToMeters(deltaLongitude, currentLatitude);
    double yDistance = latitudeToMeters(deltaLatitude);

    double headingRadians = poss * (pi / 180);

    double adjustedX = (xDistance * cos(headingRadians)) - (yDistance * sin(headingRadians));
    double adjustedZ = (xDistance * sin(headingRadians)) + (yDistance * cos(headingRadians));



    final materialpol = ArCoreMaterial(
      color: Colors.red,
    );
    final spherepol = ArCoreSphere(
      materials: [materialpol],
      radius: 0.5,
    );

    sphereNode = ArCoreNode(
      name: "123",
      shape: spherepol,

      position: vector.Vector3(adjustedX, -1.0, adjustedZ),
      scale: vector.Vector3(1.0,1.0,1.0),
    );

    arCoreController?.addArCoreNode(sphereNode!);
  }
}

Future<CompassXEvent?> deviceCompass() async {
  _lastRead = await CompassX.events!.first;
  return _lastRead;
}


double latitudeToMeters(double deltaLatitude) {
  return deltaLatitude * 111574;
}

double longitudeToMeters(double deltaLongitude, double latitude) {
  double metersPerDegree = 111574 * cos(latitude * (pi / 180));
  double longitudeInMeters = deltaLongitude * metersPerDegree;
  return longitudeInMeters;
}

